# Does passing an interface using the "in" parameter modifier prevent value copies if that interface is implemented on a readonly struct?

Tags: c#

I have an interface that is implemented on several `readonly` structs that are passed around in a tight loop using the `in` parameter modifier. My understanding of the `in` keyword is that it can be used when passing readonly structs to prevent values from being copied, thus improving performance, especially if the structs are not small.

```
public interface ISomeInterface { }

public readonly struct SomeStruct : ISomeInterface { }

public void DoSomething(in SomeStruct someStruct) { }
```

This interface will only be implemented on readonly structs. I want to know if the `in` keyword will prevent value copies if the method parameter is of type `ISomeInterface`:

```
SomeStruct someStruct = new SomeStruct(...);
DoSomethingElse(in someStruct);

public void DoSomethingElse(in ISomeInterface someInterface) { }
```

I am not sure about this because `someStruct` is a readonly struct, but the method defines it as `ISomeInterface`.

Comment: Why not try it yourself and find out?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, yeah, `in` (or `ref`, or `ref readonly`) can be used to avoid copies, and are good if your `structs` are big and you care about that performance.

But it's meaningless here because those structs are implicitly converted to an interface type in that method call. And here's a thing about interfaces: they're reference types. So, when you convert, implicitly or otherwise, a struct to an interface it implements, that struct instance gets boxed, just like you'd get if you converted it to `object`.

So, a for some struct `st` of type `SomeStruct`, a call like this:

```
DoSomethingElse(st);
```

produces this IL:

```
ldloc.0
box Program/SomeStruct
stloc.1
ldloca.s 1
call void Program::DoSomethingElse(class Program/ISomeInterface&)
nop
```

As you see, there's a box in there, so there isn't much gain in passing it by reference.

An alternative is to declare the method as generic with the right constraints:

```
public void DoSomethingElse<T>(in T someInterface) where T : struct, ISomeInterface { }
```

Calling that method instead like the sample above produces this IL instead:

```
ldloca.s 0
call void Program::DoSomethingElse<valuetype Program/SomeStruct>(!!0&)
nop
```

As you can see, there's no unnecessary boxing.